# OpenCV ArUco markers, how to get the center of them?

Tags: c++, opencv, aruco

I'm using ArUco markers and I'd like to get the coordinates of the center of a marquer. This method [detectMarkers()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/d9/d6a/group__aruco.html#gab9159aa69250d8d3642593e508cb6baa) followed by the [drawDetectedMarkers()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/d9/d6a/group__aruco.html#ga2ad34b0f277edebb6a132d3069ed2909) draws the Id of the marker. It looks like the bottom left pixel of the word "Id" is placed in the center.
How can I get the coordinates so I can print them on my frame without doing pose estimation (if possible)?

Comment: Do you need the center as pixels or as meters?

Comment: i need the pixel coordinates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have the 4 vertices, the center is simply their mean (as you can see also in the [OpenCV implementation for `drawDetectedMarkers`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/7d64747a1bbcc4c27641a3f4b50804851db3eb2a/modules/aruco/src/aruco.cpp#L1573-L1576))

```
Point2f cent(0, 0);
for(int p = 0; p < 4; p++)
    cent += currentMarker.ptr< Point2f >(0)[p];
cent = cent / 4.;
```

So your code should look like ([see also the tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d5/dae/tutorial_aruco_detection.html)):

```
cv::Mat inputImage;
...
std::vector<int> markerIds;
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f>> markerCorners, rejectedCandidates;
cv::Ptr<cv::aruco::DetectorParameters> parameters = cv::aruco::DetectorParameters::create();
cv::Ptr<cv::aruco::Dictionary> dictionary = cv::aruco::getPredefinedDictionary(cv::aruco::DICT_6X6_250);
cv::aruco::detectMarkers(inputImage, dictionary, markerCorners, markerIds, parameters, rejectedCandidates);

// Draw marker centers
cv::Mat outputImage = inputImage.clone();
for(const auto& corners : markerCorners) 
{
    cv::Point2f center(0.f, 0.f);

    // corners.size() == 4
    for(const auto& corner : corners) {
        center += corner;
    }
    center /= 4.f;
    cv::circle(outputImage, center, 3, cv::Scalar(255,0,0));
}

cv::imshow("centers", outputImage);
cv::waitKey();
```

Comment: It works thank you, I had the idea to see what drawDetectedMarkers() did but for some reason I only checked the documentation and not the code itself.

Comment: Hey again, why did you make "center" be composed of float values? I tried just normal integers and nothing changes even the calculated center displays a float value (i don't know why since i removed the appended ".f".

Comment: @Username101 the mean of integer values is not necessarily an integer (mean of [1,2] is 1.5). "center" is a point with float coordinates, so if you pass integers (0,0) or float (0.f, 0.f) or double (0.0, 0.0) the coordinates will always be float. "cv::circle" will draw at integer coordinates, so if you pass a "Point2f" it will be casted to a "Point1i / Point" with integer coordinates.